# Azure Function with Java: configure batchSize and newBatchThreshold efficiently

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm considering to use such a solution when Function is triggered by Queue on Java. I'm trying to understand how to configure batchSize and newBatchThreshold more efficiently. I would like to mention below what I managed to find out about it. Please correct me as soon as you find a mistake in my reasoning:

1. Function is executed on 1 CPU-core environment;
2. Function polls messages from Queue in batches with size 16 by default and executes them in ***parallel*** (right from the documentation);

so I make a conclusion that:

3. if messages need CPU-intensive tasks - they are executed ***sequentially***;

so I make a conclusion that:

4. since processing of messages starts at the same time (when batch arrived) then processing of more last messages takes ***longer and longer*** (confirmed experimentally);
5. all these longer and longer processings are ***billable*** (despite Function's body execution lasts 10 times less);

so I make a conclusion that:

6. One should set both batchSize and newBatchThreshold to 1 for CPU-intensive tasks and can vary only for non-CPU intensive tasks (looks like only IO-intensive tasks).

Does it make sense?

Comment: I've never thought of this, but sounds reasonable